# linux virtual memory attach/detach signal

Tags: linux, memory, signals, ipc

Q: Is it possible to receive a notification from the kernel when the system-wide number of virtual memory mappings for a page of virtual memory which is mapped in the current process changes?

The use case is for a shared memory IPC channel. I have a problem right now where, if one of the peers crashes and dies, the other peer never finds out and hangs.

In the analogous case with pipes, the peer would read end-of-file on the pipe if the other side has disappeared (because all its file descriptors would be closed), or receive SIGPIPE when writing to the pipe.

Comment: Could you provide some [mre] in your question please? I don't understand the use case. Are you coding a kernel driver, or just some Linux userland application?

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to receive a notification from the kernel when the system-wide number of virtual memory mappings for a page of virtual memory which is mapped in the current process changes?

In general it is difficult or impossible, but recent Linux kernels have added a [userfaultfd(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/userfaultfd.2.html) system call. I never used it, and cannot even name programs using it. Maybe [systemd](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Systemd) does use that.

> The use case is for a shared memory IPC channel. I have a problem right now where, if one of the peers crashes and dies

I would recommend using some *other* inter process communication (in *addition* of shared memory) for synchronization purposes. I am thinking of not only [shm_overview(7)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/shm_overview.7.html) but also [sem_overview(7)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/sem_overview.7.html), [unix(7)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/unix.7.html), [fifo(7)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/fifo.7.html), [pthreads(7)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/pthreads.7.html). If you use pipes or sockets for interprocess communication, the other one will get notified. You probably could setup a socket between both processes and the other one will notice when the peer process dies.

AFAIK, you won't be able to use [inotify(7)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/inotify.7.html) facilities on file descriptors under `/proc/` or `/sys/` (see [proc(5)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.6.html)). But if [mmap(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html) is used on *real* disk files, `inotify` becomes relevant.

If your question is about kernel to process communication, consider also [netlink(7)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/netlink.7.html) and see also [signal(7)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html) and [signalfd(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/signalfd.2.html).

I would suggest some multi-threaded approach. Read some good [pthreads tutorial](https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/pthreads/).

You might consider using [ptrace(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/ptrace.2.html). It *is* tricky.